# How to add default errback for Scrapy requests

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a bunch of spiders inherited from my base spider. What I want to have is an errback that will be called in case of request failure. I don't want to change any of my spiders except for the base one.

What I often experience in these spiders is `ResponseNeverReceived` exception, which is the reason callbacks are never called and subsequent requests are not triggered.

I want to have a default errback for all of requests, so that in case of any exception like `twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived` or `twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed` I could trigger a different request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved it with a custom middleware that I enabled for the base spider.

The snippet I used in the middleware:

```
if hasattr(spider, 'default_errback') and request.errback is None:
    request.errback = spider.default_errback
```